# What about ternary relations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, relations

There is a huge amount of concepts related to binary relations, their properties (reflexivity, symmetry, antisymmetry, transitiveness), and the bundles of their properties (partial orders, equivalence relations, etc.). In addition, it is well know how to compute the number of relations of certain kind for binary relations (how many reflexive binary relations exist in a set of size n? how many symmetric relationships exist between two finite sets?, etc.).

But, what interesting facts or properties have been proposed for ternary relations, generalizing the work on binary relations?

Comment: In fact, you can do it for any positive integer. For a set $X$ and any $n>0$, the $n$-ary relation is just a subset $R_n$ in the Cartesian product $X^n$. By this means, one say $(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n)$ has such $n$-ary relation if it's in $R_n$.